# Oracle SQL Developer Subscriber - Creating a Cross Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `UPCALL_HISTORY` that has 3 columns: `SUBSCRIBER_ID`, `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`. Let the number of unique subscribers be `N`.

I want to create a new table with 3 columns:

1. `SUBSCRIBER_ID`: All of the unique subscriber ids repeated 36 times in a row.
2. `MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID`: For each `SUBSCRIBER_ID`, this column will have dates listed from July 2015 until July 2018 (36 months).
3. `ACTIVE`: This column will be used as a flag for each subscriber and whether they have a subscription during that month. This subscription data is in a table called `UPCALL_HISTORY`.

I am fairly new to SQL, don't have a lot of experience. I am good at Python but it seems that SQL doesn't work like Python.

Any query ideas that could help me build this table?

Let my `UPCALL_HISTORY` table be:

```
+---------------+------------+------------+
| SUBSCRIBER_ID | START_DATE |  END_DATE  |
+---------------+------------+------------+
|           119 | 01/07/2015 | 01/08/2015 |
|           120 | 01/08/2015 | 01/09/2015 |
|           121 | 01/09/2015 | 01/10/2015 |
+---------------+------------+------------+
```

I want a table that looks like:

```
+---------------+------------+--------+
| SUBSCRIBER_ID |   MON_CA   | ACTIVE |
+---------------+------------+--------+
| 119           | 01/07/2015 |      1 |
| *             | 01/08/2015 |      0 |
| *             | 01/09/2015 |      0 |
| (36 times)    | 01/10/2015 |      0 |
| *             | *          |      0 |
| 119           | 01/07/2018 |      0 |
+---------------+------------+--------+
```

that continues for `120` and `121`

#### EDIT: Added Example

Comment: In your example why is 119 not shown as active in August - is the rule that they are active from whichever month the start date is in up to the month *before* the end date? What if the end date was 31/08/2015?

Comment: To be active, I am only checking whether if the start date is between that given month. I think its not the best way to go but I believe I can work it out later.

Comment: What version of the Oracle database are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also believe this is can be an example for `CROSS JOIN`. All I had to do was create a small table of all of the dates and then `CROSS JOIN` it with the table of subscribers.

Example: https://www.essentialsql.com/cross-join-introduction/

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understood the question.

Sample table and several rows:

```
SQL> create table upcall_history
  2    (subscriber_id number,
  3     start_date    date,
  4     end_date      date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into upcall_history
  2    select 1, date '2015-12-25', date '2016-01-13' from dual union
  3    select 1, date '2017-07-10', date '2017-07-11' from dual union
  4    select 2, date '2018-01-01', date '2018-04-24' from dual;

3 rows created.
```

Create a *new table*. For distinct `SUBSCRIBER_ID's`, it creates 36 "monthly" rows, fixed (as you stated).

```
SQL> create table new_table as
  2    select
  3      x.subscriber_id,
  4      add_months(date '2015-07-01', column_value - 1) monthly_calendar_id,
  5      0 active
  6    from (select distinct subscriber_id from upcall_history) x,
  7         table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                             connect by level <= 36
  9                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

Table created.
```

Update `ACTIVE` column value to "1" for rows whose `MONTHLY_CALENDAR_ID` is contained in `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` of the `UPCALL_HISTORY` table.

```
SQL> merge into new_table n
  2    using (select subscriber_id, start_date, end_date from upcall_history) x
  3    on (    n.subscriber_id = x.subscriber_id
  4        and n.monthly_calendar_id between trunc(x.start_date, 'mm')
  5                                      and trunc(x.end_date, 'mm')
  6       )
  7  when matched then
  8    update set n.active = 1;

7 rows merged.

SQL>
```

Result (only `ACTIVE = 1`):

```
SQL> select * from new_table
  2  where active = 1
  3  order by subscriber_id, monthly_calendar_id;

SUBSCRIBER_ID MONTHLY_CA     ACTIVE
------------- ---------- ----------
            1 2015-12-01          1
            1 2016-01-01          1
            1 2017-07-01          1
            2 2018-01-01          1
            2 2018-02-01          1
            2 2018-03-01          1
            2 2018-04-01          1

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 12c you can use an inline view of all the months with `cross apply` to get the combinations of those with all IDs:

```
select uh.subscriber_id, m.month,
  case when trunc(uh.start_date, 'MM') <= m.month
      and (uh.end_date is null or uh.end_date >= add_months(m.month, 1))
    then 1 else 0 end as active
from upcall_history uh
cross apply (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), - level) as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 36
) m
order by uh.subscriber_id, m.month;
```

I've made it a rolling 36-months window up to the current month, but you may actually want fixed dates as you had in the question.

With sample data from a CTE:

```
with upcall_history (subscriber_id, start_date, end_date) as (
  select 1, date '2015-09-04', '2015-12-15' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2017-12-04', '2018-05-15' from dual
)
```

that generates 72 rows:

```
SUBSCRIBER_ID MONTH          ACTIVE
------------- ---------- ----------
            1 2015-07-01          0
            1 2015-08-01          0
            1 2015-09-01          1
            1 2015-10-01          1
            1 2015-11-01          1
            1 2015-12-01          0
            1 2016-01-01          0
...
            2 2017-11-01          0
            2 2017-12-01          1
            2 2018-01-01          1
            2 2018-02-01          1
            2 2018-03-01          1
            2 2018-04-01          1
            2 2018-05-01          0
            2 2018-06-01          0
```

You can use that to create a new table, or populate an existing table; though if you *do* want a rolling window then a view might be more appropriate.

---

If you aren't on 12c then `cross apply` isn't available - you'll get "ORA-00905: missing keyword".

You can get the same result with two CTEs (one to get all the months, the other to get all the IDs)  cross-joined, and then outer joined to your actual data:

```
with m (month) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), - level)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 36
),
i (subscriber_id) as (
  select distinct subscriber_id
  from upcall_history
)
select i.subscriber_id, m.month,
  case when uh.subscriber_id is null then 0 else 1 end as active
from m
cross join i
left join upcall_history uh
on uh.subscriber_id = i.subscriber_id
and trunc(uh.start_date, 'MM') <= m.month
and (uh.end_date is null or uh.end_date >= add_months(m.month, 1))
order by i.subscriber_id, m.month;
```

Comment: Which table are you referring to as `m`?

Comment: @MertKarakas - `m` is the alias I gave to the cross-apply clause, for the generated list of all months.

Comment: Hmm interesting... I and getting a "missing keyword" error at the `cross apply` line.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't on 12c then, so this approach won't work for you.

Comment: @MertKarakas - I've added an equivalent for 11g and earlier. Might be interesting to see how these perform vs. Littlefoot's approach; same underlying idea, just coming at it from different angles.

Comment: Appreciate it! I am trying to work out Littlefoots answer. If it doesn't work, I'll try yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 11g using Partitioned Outer Joins, like so:

```
WITH upcall_history AS (SELECT 119 subscriber_id, to_date('01/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 120 subscriber_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('01/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date FROM dual UNION ALL
                        SELECT 121 subscriber_id, to_date('01/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('01/10/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date FROM dual),
              mnths AS (SELECT add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), + 1 - LEVEL) mnth
                        FROM   dual
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 * 3 + 1)
SELECT uh.subscriber_id,
       m.mnth,
       CASE WHEN mnth BETWEEN start_date AND end_date - 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END active
FROM   mnths m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN upcall_history uh PARTITION BY (uh.subscriber_id) ON (1=1)
ORDER BY uh.subscriber_id,
         m.mnth;

SUBSCRIBER_ID MNTH            ACTIVE
------------- ----------- ----------
          119 01/07/2015           1
          119 01/08/2015           0
          119 01/09/2015           0
          119 01/10/2015           0
          <snip>
          119 01/06/2018           0
          119 01/07/2018           0
          --
          120 01/07/2015           0
          120 01/08/2015           1
          120 01/09/2015           0
          120 01/10/2015           0
          <snip>
          120 01/06/2018           0
          120 01/07/2018           0
          --
          121 01/07/2015           0
          121 01/08/2015           0
          121 01/09/2015           1
          121 01/10/2015           0
          <snip>
          121 01/06/2018           0
          121 01/07/2018           0
```

N.B. I have assumed some things about your start/end dates and what constitutes active; hopefully it should be easy enough for you to tweak the case statement to fit the logic that works best for your situation.